# Как обойти CORS, CORB при получении данных через API на Angular

Tags: javascript, json, api, angular

Пишу веб-приложение на Angular, которое должно получать данные с биржи через API. Я только учусь и поэтому начал с локального файла .json - он является полной копией ответа с сервера биржи. Всё - ок, данные читаются и выводятся в окне браузера, но как только я прописываю путь до сервера в консоли браузера появляется ошибка "Доступ заблокирован политикой CORS" и соответственно данные не выводятся.

Попытка обойти ошибку путём включения режима "no-cors" приводит к другим ошибкам - "Блокировка чтения из разных источников (CORB)" и "Невозможно прочитать свойство '0'"

Помогите пожалуйста понять причины этих ошибок и найти грамотное решение.

Приложение размещено на stackblitz.com, там можно редактировать его. Вот ссылки на файлы:

[http.service.ts](https://stackblitz.com/edit/bybit-angular-api?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhttp.service.ts) - файл сервиса

[app.component.ts](https://stackblitz.com/edit/bybit-angular-api?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) - файл компонента

[app.component.html](https://stackblitz.com/edit/bybit-angular-api?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) - html файл

Comment: Отправляйте запрос сервера, а не с браузера. CORS работает в браузере это политика

Comment: Я делал расширения Chrom и мне в такой ситуации помогла установка в браузер другого расширения - https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cors-unblock/lfhmikememgdcahcdlaciloancbhjino?hl=ru для обхода CORS, проблем с использованием собственного расширения потом не имел..

Comment: @Valentin Это только вашего хрома касается. Если это публичный сайт то как вы будите просить пользователя что он установил расширение

Comment: А как можно с сервера отправить запрос в Angular? Я уже копал в эту сторону, но не нашёл пока решения...

Comment: fetch на сервер. Который делает fetch на лево ответ пересылаем

Comment: @Aziz Если я правильно вас понял нужен ещё один сервер для выполнения этой манипуляции? Если да, то не является ли это лишним действием? Может быть обработку запроса можно как-то сделать на одном и том же сервере - где размещено приложение и там же например произвести запись полученных данных в файл, и уже из него производить чтение для отображения в браузере?

Comment: @WAVE У вас точно есть сервер который поднимает ваш сайт на ангуляр. Добавьте тару роутов которые будут пересылать данные на клиента из другого сервиса